# ASP.NET Boilerplate adding an additional log file with Log4Net and Castle Logging

Tags: log4net, aspnetboilerplate

I've been trying to find documentation and guidance on how to use a separate log file in ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC.

It's straight forward to inject ILogger and push messages into the default Log.txt file, however I need a separate log file to record a lot of batch job messages and keep things tidy.

I can't find any methods to use another log from the Log4Net.config file.   Can anyone advise on the correct code / configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer by chance in looking at the Hangfire documentation, where it was shown you can configure Hangfire messages to be sent to another log file by getting Log4Net to listen for the Hangfire name and route based on that.

With the following additional configuration in Log4Net.config I now have Log messages created normally within MyClass sent to the MyClass.txt log file:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender_MyClass" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <file value="App_Data/Logs/MyClass.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="32" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%-5.5thread] %-40.40logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger additivity="false" name="MyNamespace.MyClass">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender_MyClass" />
</logger>
```

And for completeness, it's called in the standard way documented within the AspNet Boilerplate documentation:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging

Answer (score 0):

### Way-1:

In this sample, the default log file is `App_Data/Logs/Logs.txt`.

But when I use the logger in the namespace `MySite.Web.Controllers.PaymentController`, the logs will be written in `App_Data/Logs/PaymentLogs.txt`

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="App_Data/Logs/Logs.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%-5.5thread] %-40.40logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender_PaymentController" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="App_Data/Logs/PaymentLogs.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="32" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%-5.5thread] %-40.40logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </root>

  <logger name="NHibernate">
    <level value="WARN" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="MySite.Web.Controllers.PaymentController" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender_PaymentController" />
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </logger>

</log4net>
```

---

### Way-2:

You can get a specific logger by calling `LogManager.GetLogger()` with a appender name.

```
private static readonly ILog paymentLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("MySite.Web.Controllers.PaymentController");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however this doesn't seem to work with ASP.NET Boilerplate.  Both ILog and LogManager don't resolve.  ILogger doesn't have a method of GetLogger. 

In your first option, I'm not clear on how to bind the appender (by name presumably) to my service class that I wan't to log from, which is Project.Images.ImageManager.